# iphone fbconnect. does it work with OS 2.2.1?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fbconnect

does fbconnect works with iphone OS 2.2.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download the [project source code](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk/), the base SDK is set at iPhone OS 2.0.  This would seem to indicate that it can be build for 2.x, but I no longer have the 2.0 SDK on my machine, so I can't test this out.